# How many cards needed to write out all 61 digit numbers (rotating cards is allowed)?

Tags: combinatorics

*"There are $10^{61}$ different 61-digit numbers (where leading zeros are
allowed). These numbers are written out on cards. Regard two cards as the same, if one of them can be
turned into the other by rotating it. For example 0016989 would be the same as 6869100 (Here, we assume 0, 1 and 8 are unchanged by rotation, while 9 turns into six, and vice-versa).*

*How many different cards are there?"*

I am stuck working on this problem; here are my thoughts so far.

If we have a $2, 3, 4, 5, 7$ appearing anywhere in the number, it will mean nothing when flipped. So we require a seperate card for each of these numbers.

There are $5^{61}$ cards with exactly $0$ of these digits - thus we need at least $10^{61}-5^{61}$ cards for these 'un-flippable' numbers.

There are $5^{61}$ numbers that can be flipped. So I could say $\frac{5^{61}}{2}$ cards to cover each of these numbers, but this would be incorrect, as some of the cards flip into the same number - so we actually need more than this.

This is where I am stuck - how to enumerate the cards that flip into the same number? Any hints or ideas are much appreciated.

EDIT: I figured out that, for cards that flip into themselves, we only have to consider the first 31 digits - the rest are determined by these. We have $5^{30}$ choices for the first 30 digits (they can be any 'flippable' number), then the middle digit must be either a $0, 1, 8$ (to remain unchanged by the flip). Thus there are $5^{30}3$ cards that flip into themselves - sound correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$0, 1,6, 8,9$ can be rotated.

So there are $10^{61}$ numbers.  And $5^{61}$ numbers can be turned upside down.

The numbers that can be turned upside down to get that same number again is where the number in position $61$ is the same as the number in position position $1$ upside down, and the number in position $60$ is the number in position $2$ upside down.  And so on.  Meanwhile the number in the middle, position $31$, must flip to itself-- that is must be $0,1$ or $8$. So there are $3*5^{30}$ numbers that when turned upside will be themselves.

So there are $5^{61} - 3*5^{30}$ cards that can be turned to another number if we turn them upside down.  As one these card represent $2$ numbers we only need half of these.

But we need all the rest.

So we need $10^{61}- \frac {5^{61}-3*5^{30}}2=$

Comment: Thank you, but I think you forgot that the digit 8 can also be rotated...

Comment: Yep...Totally forgot that.  Replace the fours with fives.

Comment: Not the only mistake I made.  (Not sure why I briefly forgot these were 61 digit number and briefly assumed these were $4$ digit numbers....)

Comment: No problem. Thank you for the revised answer!